# How do I walk through path of a google bucket in notebook?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-lab, bucket

I have a large dataset of images in a zip file. I want to list all the files so I can work with them.

Since a while I started using google cloud platform and I uploaded my data to a bucket. When working local, I used this piece of code to find the filenames of all the files in the dataset. I want to do something similar so I can load the images in my notebook.

```
#files directory in list 
matches = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("D:\LH\..."):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.nii'):
        matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename)) 

print(matches[0])
```

Since my dataset is split up in 10 different zip files, I have this piece of code to list the objects in my bucket:

```
from google.cloud import storage


def list_blobs(bucket_name):
    """Lists all the blobs in the bucket."""
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    # Note: Client.list_blobs requires at least package version 1.17.0.
    blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name)

    for blob in blobs:
        print(blob.name)

bloblist = list_blobs('adni_data')
```

which gives me a list with the folders where my files are in. But how can I load this data using the nilearn library? Btw, the folders consist of many folders with more folders after which the file is stored (every file in other folders).

Answer (score 0):

By iterating over all the blobs with `list_blobs`, you're just getting *references* to where the data exists in Cloud Storage -- no actual image data has been transferred between GCS and your script.

If you wanted to load the image with something like [`nilearn.image.load_img`](https://nilearn.github.io/modules/generated/nilearn.image.load_img.html), you need a path to a *local* `.nii` file, so you'd need to do something like:

```py
for blob in blobs:
    local_filename = '/tmp/' + blob.name
    blob.download_to_filename(local_filename)
    nilearn.image.load_img(local_filename)
```

Comment: Thank you! I really expected this to work, however I got the following error message for blob.download_to_file: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'.

Comment: Oops, sorry! That should be `download_to_filename`.